# Controls of Appium server GUI is in disable mode

Tags: android, appium

Whenever I am opening the `Appium server` in the `GUI mode` (*appium.exe*) , the controls example: Android settings, General settings remains disabled.

I am not able to click the check-box to change the values like `No reset` as the check box remains disabled.

The versions I am using is :

> Appium : 1.4.0.0
>
> Node js : 0.12.4

I have also configured android properly to my system.

Answer (score 1):

You should launch the GUI mode (appium.exe), but don't start the server to edit the settings(preferences). if you want to edit the the settings, please stop the server first then edit.

Comment: Thank you Ashish for the solution. It is working now.